# Issues compiling Laravel, Webpack and Sparkline

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm trying to implement the [Sparkline JavaScript package](https://github.com/fnando/sparkline) in my Laravel 5.8 project using Laravel Mix. Sparkline will not display, and I get the following browser console error.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: sparkline is not defined.

I'm not invoking it properly.

Heres my steps:

Install the sparkline package with npm

```
npm install @fnando/sparkline --save-dev
```

and confirm the package is present in node_modules (`node_modules/@fnando/sparkline`)

Add an entry to my webpack.mix.js:

```
mix.js([
    'resources/js/app.js',
    'node_modules/@fnando/sparkline'
    ],'public/js');
```

Include an import in my `./resources/js/app.js`:

```
import sparkline from "@fnando/sparkline"
```

Run webpack with `npm run dev` which produces assets: `./public/js/app.js.`

They are referenced in my master layout blade like so:

```html
[.. snip ..]
        <script src="{{ asset('js/resources.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('js/semantic.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

        <script>
        $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
        $('.ui.sticky').sticky({
            offset: 50,
            context: '#content'
        });

        @stack('inline_scripts')
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Finally, I try to render the sparkline in my blade like so:

```html
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

<div class="ui secondary segment">
    <h4>Sparklines!</h4>
    <div class="ui two column centered grid">
        <div class="column">
            <svg class="sparkline" width="100" height="30" stroke-width="3"></svg>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

@push('inline_scripts')
sparkline.sparkline(document.querySelector(".sparkline"), [1, 5, 2, 4, 8, 3, 7]);
@endpush

@endsection
```

Comment: `import` will not import globally, only in the file you've imported. Try doing `window.sparkline = sparkline` to  make it global. You don't need to actually add it to the .mix file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the jQuery Sparklines plugin as an NPM package.

```
npm install @fnando/sparkline
```

Change your Webpack file.

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .copy('node_modules/@fnando/sparkline/dist/sparkline.js', 'public/js');
```

Compile your assets.

```
npm run production
```

The package will now be compiled into `/public/js/app.js` for use in your Blade template; put it in the header towards the top of the Blade file.

```
    <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ mix('js/sparkline.js') }}"></script>
</head>
<body>

<svg class="sparkline" width="100" height="300" stroke-width="3"></svg>
<script>
    sparkline.sparkline(document.querySelector(".sparkline"), [1, 5, 2, 4, 8, 3, 7]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems the bootstrap.js change is unecessary once the webpack (`.copy()`) and blade template changes are present. Do you know why?

Comment: I removed that step. I had hoped the copy() would not be necessary and we could load the sparkline library via bootstrap.js but that didn't work. The only way I could get it to work was with .copy(). :( sorry.

Comment: no apologies needed. Your method does get it working. I appreciate the assistance and amount of work you provided.

Answer (score 0):

With help from the project [author](https://nandovieira.com), I have found that the following works:

Install the sparkline package with npm

```php
    npm install @fnando/sparkline --save-dev
```

Include an import in my ./resources/js/app.js and associate it with window

```
    import sparkline from "@fnando/sparkline"
    window.sparkline = sparkline
```

Run webpack with `npm run [dev|production]` which produces assets: `./public/js/app.js`.

Referenced these in my master layout blade like so:

```php
[.. snip ..]
        <script src="{{ asset('js/resources.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

        <script>
            @stack('inline_scripts')
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Finally, render the sparkline in my blade like so:

```html
    @extends('layouts.master')

    @section('content')

    <div>
        <h4>Sparklines!</h4>
        <div class="column">
            <svg class="sparkline" width="100" height="30" stroke-width="3"></svg>
        </div>
    </div>

    @push('inline_scripts')
        sparkline.sparkline(document.querySelector(".sparkline"), [1, 5, 2, 4, 8, 3, 7]);
    @endpush

    @endsection
```

no changes necessary to `webpack.mix.js`, the `app.js` changes appear to import and ... invoke(?) the package. I don't know why, but I would love to know.

This is materially different from the previous answer in that it bundles the JavaScript package into my compiled app.js, which could be preferable to simply serving the distributed .js locally and loading it with a `<script src="">`.